# Is it possible to Handle ftp request using servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to write a servlet which handles FTP request instead of usual HTTP request?, If yes, how can we do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it says that you can extend `GenericServlet` to use other protocols than HTTP - you can't. There's no implementation that handles the networking, especially since FTP is a statefull protocol.

I would suggest implementing something like the Apache Mina Ftp Server (http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/) to handle that for you.

Comment: The requested URL /ftpserver was not found on this server

Comment: Thanks, I guess they moved the project. Changed the URL to the new one.